# upload Multiple images to desired folder

Tags: php, database

In my website users can post multiple images...
so i want that all images uploaded by user should be stored in folder named "newsdata" and inside this folder i needed the folder named as the Id of that particular post and all images should be stored in that folder, images should be named as 1, 2, 3,....

this is what i tried

```
    <div id="upload">
      <div id="drop">
      Drop Images Here
          or
     <a>Browse</a>
     <input type="file" name="upl[]" multiple />
     </div>
     <ul>
         <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
     </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Php script:

```
$new_last_id = $_SESSION[$last_id];

mkdir ("../newsdata/" . $new_last_id, 0777);
$path="../newsdata/";
  $uploadpath = $path.$new_last_id."/";      //directory where the images are uploaded    now
 $i = '0';
    foreach ($_FILES['upl']['name'] as $filename) {
    ++$i;
    $uploadpath = $uploadpath .''.$i.'.jpg';
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['name'], $uploadpath)) { 
    $data_2 = 'True';
    }   
if($data_2)
{
header("Location:../");
}
```

but not received the desired result ....
help me out ....
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should have as many inputs as files with the same names and try the same procedure you are doing.     So  <input type="file" name="upl[]" multiple /> then <input type="file" name="upl[]" multiple /> <input type="file" name="upl[]" multiple /> etc.

Comment: Please use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; in $path variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do a `print_r($_FILES);` you can see that the output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [upl] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Desert.jpg
                    [1] => Jellyfish.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpsmBI96
                    [1] => /tmp/phpT55Qye
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 845941
                    [1] => 775702
                )

        )

)
```

ie: $_FILES['upl']['name'] is an array.

You did a `foreach ($_FILES['upl']['name'] as $filename) {...` but why are your trying to access `$_FILES['upl']['name']` inside your foreach again and pass it to `move_uploaded_file`. You should replace this with `$filename` which is your current filename.

```
foreach ($_FILES['upl']['name'] as $filename) {
    ++$i;
    $uploadpath = $uploadpath .''.$i.'.jpg';
    if(move_uploaded_file($filename, $uploadpath)) { 
        $data_2 = 'True';
    }   
    [...]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help and I applied your code, only folder gets created but that folder is empty no images in them .....!!!